# Can I run a sql statement from a dag without a template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jinja2, airflow

I tried using the BigQueryInsertJobOperator to run a .sql file to insert data in to a table. I get an error saying no template found. Looking into templates they look like quite complex to build... is there anyway from airflow dag to just  run a one off script with the given SA? Or is it not that easy?

Comment: Can you provide your python code? This is for the community to properly replicate your use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418384/using-bq-insert-job-operator-but-unable-to-define-sa-to-use-in-dag

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware I still had this question out there... check the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding code as you requested.

```
project_id = ''
client = bigquery.Client()

query_job = client.query("""
INSERT INTO `ProjectC.dataset.table` (Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT (Col1, Col2, 
Col3) FROM `ProjectB.dataset.table`
""")
results = query_job.result()
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a way in python to tell it which SA to use when executing the query? Without actually authenticating as said SA. Like when I pass in an SA to my dataflow args.

Comment: If you are using this in a Dag , it should use Composer service account by default.

Comment: Yeah but the composer service account doesn't have all necessary permissions for the different datasets etc. It does have Service Account User role though, so I need to figure out how to tell it which service account to use when executing? Any ideas?

Comment: you can add it in the python file with one line  , where key.json is your custom SA key you would create for this.

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= 'key.json'

Comment: Sorry maybe this is my lack of understanding or a whole new question in its self. What I mean is that I already authenticate as an SA that has Service Account User permission. Therefore I don't expect to have to re authenticate as a whole new SA, just tell the code which SA to execute as, and as my primary SA has the SA user role it should be able to execute as that SA with out needing a key for the executing SA... do you understand what I mean?

Comment: If you are having problems with the authentication side, you may post it as a new question for the community to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for the same

```
t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='Export_to_gcs',
bash_command ='python /home/airflow/gcs/dags/Scripts/insert_into_bigquery.py',
dag=dag)
```

You can create a folder called **Scripts** in your dags main folder and put your main script in a folder.

You can pass this file path in your bash command.

This is the way i found most optimized .

Let me know if you need sample code to load data into BigQuery using python , i will be able to help you with that

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up taking this approach 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418384/using-bq-insert-job-operator-but-unable-to-define-sa-to-use-in-dag but got the error explained. Any thoughts

Comment: The approach you tried and what we suggested is different. In your approach you are using Insert Query in your Dag file.  What I am suggesting is - Use seperate python code e.q insert_into_bq.py  to insert data in bigquery and just pass that file as python code in Dag. Read my answer again.

Comment: I do like this approach though... if you could provide sample python that would be great. Also, are you able to tell it which SA to use in the python code?

Comment: shared in another answer